# async task is not Working in WorkManagers CallbackDispatcher

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, flutter-plugin

I am using WorkManager for Background Service. My code is as follows

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case "uploadLocalData":
        print("this method was called from background!");
        await BackgroundProcessHandler().uploadLocalData();
        print("background Executed!");
        return true;
       
        break;
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        print("iOS background fetch delegate ran");
        return true;
        break;
    }
    return false;
   
  });
}
```

is there any way to wait for async method in executeTask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to asyncify non-async things is through completers. You create a completer, await on its future and complete it in the future.

```
Completer uploadCompleter = Completer();

void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager.executeTask((task, inputData) async {
    switch (task) {
      case "uploadLocalData":
        print("this method was called from background!");
        await BackgroundProcessHandler().uploadLocalData();
        print("background Executed!");
        uploadCompleter.complete();
        return true;
       
        break;
      case Workmanager.iOSBackgroundTask:
        print("iOS background fetch delegate ran");
        return true;
        break;
    }
    return false;
   
  });
}

// somewhere else
await uploadCompleter.future;
```

Comment: just added ```await uploadCompleter.future;``` above to the ```uploadCompleter.complete();```, this worked perfectly for me. Thanks  @GazihanAlankus

Comment: I'm glad it helped, but I don't undersdand :) If you `await uploadCompleter.future;` before `uploadCompleter.complete();`, it will never get to `uploadCompleter.complete();`, right?

Comment: I'm also shocked, bcoz conceptually it's wrong,.. but it worked for me.